# ClassCastException while starting a Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Seeing a mysterious ClassCastException while starting my spring boot application. 
I started seeing this issue very recently without any change in any configuration. 
How do we debug this issue?

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer
at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.Bootstrap.handleDeployment(Bootstrap.java:62) ~[undertow-websockets-jsr-1.3.5.Final.jar:1.3.5.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.handleExtensions(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:246) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.5.Final.jar:1.3.5.Final]
```

**Info:** 
Here's the [build info](http://pastebin.ca/3329365)

Comment: Looks like you have both the Tomcat and Undertow starters included. Post your POM or Gradle build.

Comment: Here it [is](http://pastebin.ca/3329365).

Comment: Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need this dependency.

> > ```
> > <dependency>
> >      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
> >      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
> >    </dependency>
> > ```

And if you are going to use tomcat server, you don't need any tomcat dependencies, since default container is **Tomcat** in spring boot.

> > ```
> > <dependency>
> >             <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
> >             <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
> >             <scope>provided</scope>
> >     </dependency>
> >     <dependency>
> >             <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
> >             <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
> >             <scope>provided</scope>
> >     </dependency>
> > ```

Ref [SpringBoot EmbeddedContainers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html)